# Virtual vs. Physical Computer

Tags: assembly, x86, virtualbox, boot

I am writing a little Lambda-calculus program in assembly. I ran it with VirtualBox and it worked perfectly, but when I copied the code into the bootsector of my USB-drive and booted my computer from it, it didn't work.

I've isolated the problem to be in the initial loading of an extra sector containing the function library. Here is the code snippet in question:

```
PUSH 0x2000
POP ES           ;segment 0x2000
MOV BX, 0x0000   ;offset
MOV CX, 0x0002   ;sector 2 and track 0
MOV DX, 0x0080   ;drive 80 and head 0
load:
MOV AX, 0x0201   ;read only one sector
INT 0x13         ;read sector
JC load          ;repeat until no error
MOV BX, 0x0007
MOV AH, 0x0E
MOV AL, [ES:0x0000]
INT 0x10         ;print a '!' character to test if the process is successful (purely for debugging reasons)
```

So with VirtualBox I get a nice ! to show that the loading process was successful, yet on my computer it gives me a black space (ASCII 0x00). Anyone any suggestions as to what might be the problem here.

Comment: no idea, but please write a blog post on this when you get it working!

Comment: Possible that your USB drive thinks it's drive 0, not drive 80h?

Comment: The BIOS is supposed to load the boot drive number into the `DL` register for you so using that should eliminate that problem.

Comment: I wish it were that simple, but I've already tried without setting DX to a specific value (because the BIOS sets DL to the drive number it just booted from) but that didn't work either. Just to be on the save side I've set the drive number to 0, but it just gets stuck in the "JC load" loop.

Comment: You also get back an error code, have you looked at that?

Comment: No, that's the whole point. If there was an error CF would be set and the program would try again. Though that is not the case, there is no error. In fact as far as I can see and have checked, every thing does what is should except for the missing sector...

Comment: So maybe you simply have a problem putting the extra sector on the usb drive? Have you checked it's there?

Comment: The data is there, that was the very first thing I checked. I used a hex editor to put is there, so it is were it should be. It just doesn't go were it should.

Comment: @Erik, you should answer your own question by providing an answer below, instead of editing your question.

Comment: Erik, please add an answer with your solution and remove it from your post, and also remove the "[Solved]". That way, the system can see that an answer has been found, and you can accept your answer to show that it has been solved. This will make your question fit better with the rest of the site, since those are the things the system looks for to determine if a question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem. It turns out that my code was located in the first two sectors of the logical disk. Although there is only one logical disk on my USB-drive, my hex editor excludes the first 2048 sector of the physical disk when opening as logical disk. Were windows sees this distinction, for the CPU it's just an array of bits. So when I loaded the second sector into memory, instead of loading the 2050th sector (for as far as I knew at the time Was the second sector) were the data was located, it loaded quite correctly the actual second sector containing, apart from some stray bits, only 0x00s.

Now that the data is in the correct sector, it works like a charm.